# "Bit Coin Investigators" or Consultants for hire - to help locate a Bit Coin account after a person has died?

Tags: wallet-recovery

Do you know where I can obtain a List of "Bit Coin Investigators"
 or  -  Consultants for hire -
to help locate a Bit Coin account after a person has died?

Comment: You're unlikely to find such a list. Wallet recovery is an inherently difficult field, and most people you'd find would be more likely to scam you than help you. If you were to post a question detailing the situation, someone here might be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. I have my grandson's computer & iPhone & drive, but don't know how to find his Bitcoin account info. He had been investing for about 4 years before he unexpectedly passed away. He happily had told me about having an account  with Bitcoins in it & I don't know anything else.

Comment: Good luck with your quest, please do be careful. The person that you trust to recover the Bitcoin wallet will have the opportunity to steal it if they are dishonest.

Answer (score 1):

> **Do you know where I can obtain a List of "Bit Coin Investigators"**

There isn't any established list.

You need to be very careful about trusting strangers on the Internet, there are many crooks looking for people like you. They will ask you for a fee to retrieve the Bitcoins, then ask for additional fees using various technical-sounding reasons until they have bled you dry.

Remember that you are putting an **extreme** amount of temptation in the hands of any potential helper, it would be so easy for them to take everything away for investigation and later tell you the "bitcoin wallet" was empty - or contained some small amount they thought would satisfy you. Even respectable people working for respectable lawfirms sometimes embezzle their customers money. The temptation is so much greater when the chances of anyone discovering their deceit can be near to zero.

> **I have my grandson's computer & iPhone & drive, but don't know how to find his Bitcoin account info.**

Unless you know his passwords, it is likely be impossible to ever gain access to any of his Bitcoins.

Unless he was an extraordinarily careless sort of person, he won't have the passwords for his bitcoins stored on his computer or on his iPhone - at least not in a form where you can easily find them.

You could try to find if he had a "paper wallet" - a piece of paper with a string of 36 digits and letters written down or a set of twelve words (sometimes there are eighteen or twenty-four words) which form what is called a "recovery phrase". If you find those, put them aside somewhere very very safe, keep them secret from any helpers, then spend some time learning how to create a bitcoin wallet on your own computer (don't use an online wallet), when you have some experience buying and spending bitcoin, only then, import the key or use the recovery phrase to gain access to your grandson's bitcoins.